# Transferring buttons value to input form

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying to create a keypad that user will use to type in a password. I believe I can figure out the whole logic behind this, but I can't figure out how after clicking one of the button display the clicked value on the input form.

My HTML looks like this:

```
 <div class="keypad">
<input type='text' id='display' placeholder='Enter Code' maxlength='4'>
<div class='keys'>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
  </div>
 <div class='row'>
   <button>blank</button>
   <button>0</button>
   <button>blank</button>
 </div>
```

And keypad looks like this 
[image]

So, to sum this up, if the user clicked 1, 4, 5, 7 buttons I want to display (while removing the placeholder text) a 1457 number.

And I would be extremely graetful for pure JS help, I dont want to use jquery here.

Comment: Please show us your own effort and theorize a way of how the code would work using logic. It doesn't look like you've done much in thinking. Remember, SO is not a place for free code. It's a place for learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to attach the `click` event to all the buttons inside the `keys` class, then append the clicked button text to the input value like, example below.

Hope his helps.

**Pure JS Snippet :**

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.keys button');

for(var i=0;i<buttons.length;i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
}

function buttonClick(){
    var display = document.getElementById('display');
       display.value += this.innerHTML;
    
    if(display.value.length == 4){
       if(display.value ==1111){
          display.value = "yay"; 
       } else { 
          display.value = "ERROR"; 
          setTimeout(newDisplay, 3000);
       }
    }
} 

function newDisplay(){ 
   display.value = null;
}
```

```html
<div class="keypad">
<input type='text' id='display' placeholder='Enter Code' maxlength='4'>
<div class='keys'>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
  </div>
 <div class='row'>
   <button>blank</button>
   <button>0</button>
   <button>blank</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery Snippet :**

```js
$('.keys button').on('click', function(){
   $('#display').val( $('#display').val() + $(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="keypad">
<input type='text' id='display' placeholder='Enter Code' maxlength='4'>
<div class='keys'>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>1</button>
    <button>2</button>
    <button>3</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>4</button>
    <button>5</button>
    <button>6</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>7</button>
    <button>8</button>
    <button>9</button>
  </div>
 <div class='row'>
   <button>blank</button>
   <button>0</button>
   <button>blank</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned above, I really dont want to use Jquery, because then I realised I wasnt able to do simple things with pure JS because of it.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! I dont know why I thought that innerHTML would not work on it.

Comment: I've added the 4 digits condition, take a i look

Comment: Great! Now I almost have it working except for last thing and I dont get what Im doing wrong. I want after a wrong passcode to display "error" on the input and then after 3 seconds clear it. Sadly it clears it immediately and I dont get why.
      if(display.value.length ==4){
        if(display.value ==1111){
          display.value = "yay";
        } else {
          display.value = "ERROR";
          setTimeout(newDisplay(), 3000)
        }
      }  
    }

    function newDisplay(){
     display.value = null;
    }

Oh i see i cant add code in those comments...

Comment: Check my update, the problem was on the parentheses after newDisplay in `setTimeout(newDisplay, 3000);`.

Comment: I guess I'm too tired because I make such simple mistakes. Thank you so much for saving a lot of my time! Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a click event listener to each button and then add the value of that button to the input value.

```
var input = document.getElementById('display');
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach(function(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(input.value.length < 4) {
      input.value += button.innerHTML;
    } else {
      alert('Sorry but you can just use 4 digits');
    }
  })
});
```

To prevent the clicks on the blank buttons to add their text to the input you can add to each numeric button a class i.e:

```
<button class="numericButton">1</button>
```

And then change the `querySelectorAll` parameter to that class:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.numericButton');
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But I need to ask about one more thing, because of this function the "maxlength" attrivute of input is overrided and I can type over 4 digits. Should I just add some kind of counter into that function that will stop it after 4 clicks? Or is there a simpler solution?

Comment: Edited the answer so the input is limited to 4 digits.

Comment: Thank you, definitely learned new things here!

Answer (score 0):

Append each number to the textbox when the button is clicked.

You should add a `onclick` event on all the buttons.

`<button onclick="updateText(this.innerText);">5</button>`

Now define a Javascript function that will update the textbox value:

`function updateText(appendText) {
document.getElementById('display').value = document.getElementById('display').value + appendText;
}`